# Failed to lookup view "profile" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

I'm trying to make a better experience of nodeJS and i don't really like to get all the script in one file.

so, i used this structure

```
./   
  public/
    css/
      styles.css
    images
  views
    index.ejs
    profile.ejs
  app.js
  routes.js
```

My files right now:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// routes
require('./routes.js')(app); 

app.listen(1337);
```

In routes.js, if I use **res.render('index')** then its working while when I use **res.render('profile')** then it is giving error **Failed to lookup view "profile" in views directory**

**routes.js**  ----- **Working**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       res.render('index');         
    });       
};
```

**routes.js**  ----- **Not Working**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       res.render('profile');         
    });       
};
```

*Assume that* **index.ejs** and **profile.ejs** *have same content.*

Can anyone explain what is the problem if I use **res.render('profile')** in routes.js

Edit: Complete Error message:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "profile" in views directory  "/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/views"
at EventEmitter.render (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
at ServerResponse.render (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
at /home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/routes2.js:10:12
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/anand03/Desktop/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

Comment: There must be something else you are not showing from your code. This code works just fine. And there's no reason it shoudn't. Can you show complete error message?

Comment: This is the exact code I am using. I am also not understanding what is the problem in this.

Comment: Are you sure the profile file has the **ejs** extension? Can you possibly place all the code somewhere public. I mean a minimal setup that reproduces the issue so i can try it.